# Remix defer() not working as expected with the most basic example. It awaits all promises before transmitting data

Tags: reactjs, async-await, shopify-app, remix, deferred-loading

I have critical data and noncritical data. Both are provided through the loader. I want to transmit the noncritical data as a promise using defer.

Given the following example, I would expect "quickAndCritical" to be rendered after about 1s and "slow" about 2s later.
But actually the page stays blank for about 3s and then renders both.

Am I making a mistake here? I would appreciate any help!

```
import React, { Suspense } from "react";
import { defer } from "@remix-run/node";
import { Await, Links, Meta, useLoaderData } from "@remix-run/react";
import type { LoaderFunction, LoaderFunctionArgs } from "@remix-run/node";

export function quickAndCritical() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve("quickAndCritical");
    }, 1000);
  });
}

export function slowAndDeferrable() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve("slow");
    }, 3000);
  });
}

export const loader: LoaderFunction = async ({ request }: LoaderFunctionArgs) => {
  const critical = await quickAndCritical();
  const canBeDeferred = slowAndDeferrable();

  return defer({
    critical,
    canBeDeferred,
  });
};

export default function App() {
  const { critical, canBeDeferred } = useLoaderData();

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
        <Meta />
        <Links />
      </head>
      <body>
        {critical}
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <Suspense fallback={null}>
          <Await resolve={canBeDeferred}>{(resolvedData) => <div>{resolvedData}</div>}</Await>
        </Suspense>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using the Shopify CLI to preview your app, this might be caused by the Cloudflare proxy which apparently does not support streaming.

[See here](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-app-template-remix/issues/323#issuecomment-1721732526) for more detail and a workaround.

Answer (score -1):

According to the [Remix Docs](https://remix.run/docs/en/main/guides/streaming), you need to initiate promises for deferred data before you await any other promises.

Swapping lines 1 & 2 should do the trick for ya.

```
export const loader: LoaderFunction = async ({ request }: LoaderFunctionArgs) => {
  const canBeDeferred = slowAndDeferrable();
  const critical = await quickAndCritical();
  

  return defer({
    critical,
    canBeDeferred,
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you. That does not fix the issue and I would have been surprised if it did. With the lines switched both `quickAndCritical` and `slow` are shown simultaneously after 3 seconds.